# Concatenate image and video without reencoding video

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Here's what I'm trying to do in order to append an image to a video and stitch them together in an output video:

```bash
# To test this code, place it in a folder containing a 'demo.mkv' file and run it. 
image="image.png"
video="demo.mkv"

# Get video properties
width=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video")
height=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video")
codec=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video")
fps=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video")
audio_codec=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video")
audio_sample_rate=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video")
audio_channels=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=channels -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video")

# Generate example image
convert -size "${width}X${height}" xc:black -font Arial -pointsize 48 -fill white -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "TEXT" "$image"

# Generate the video using FFmpeg with the properties of the input video
video_from_image=$(basename "$image")
video_from_image="${video_from_image%.*}"
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate "$fps" -i "$image" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=$audio_sample_rate:cl=$audio_channels -t 4 -c:v "$codec" -c:a "$audio_codec" -vf "scale=$width:$height" "${video_from_image}.mkv"

# Concatenate image and video
echo "file '${video_from_image}.mkv'" >> list.txt
echo "file $video" >> list.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c:v copy video.mkv
```

However, even though the output file size and length are the sum of the two input files, the output shows no frames from the input video. The only frames it shows are from the image file, the rest is just blank.